# Inequality of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, definite-integrals

I am having a problem whose statement I am skeptical is not correct: Let's say $A = \int_{0}^{1} h(x) dx$ where $h(x)$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Define $Y = h(X)$ and $Z = \frac{1}{2}(h(X) + h(1-X))$ where $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$. Prove that $Var(Z)\leq Var(Y)$.

**My attempt:** First, it is straightforward to prove that $E(Y) = E(Z) = A$. Thus, it is sufficient to show $E(Y^2)\geq E(Z^2)$. Applying the definition of expectation,

$E(Y^2) = \int_{0}^{1} h^2(x)\times 1\ dx$ (since $f_X(x) = 1$)

$E(Z^2) = \int_{0}^{1} (0.25\times h^2(x) + 0.25\times h^2(1-x) + 0.5\times h(x)h(1-x))\times 1\ dx$.

Note that $\int_{0}^{1} h^2(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} h^2(1-x) dx$.

Thus, $E(Y^2)\geq E(Z^2) \Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{1} h(x)(h(x) - h(1-x))\ dx\geq 0$.

I got stuck here, because there is no way to show $h(x)\geq h(1-x)$ (although $h(x), h(1-x)\geq 0$ by definition). Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write : $$\int_0^1 h(x)(h(x) - h(1-x))dx = \int_0^1 h^2(x) - \int_0^1 h(x)h(1-x)$$

Use Cauchy Schwarz : $$\left[\int_0^1 h(x)h(1-x)dx\right]^2 \leq \int_0^1 h^2(x)dx \int_0^1 h^2(1-x) dx = \left(\int_0^1 h^2(x)dx\right)^2$$

Square roots are positive since both inner terms must be positive by non-negativity of $h$. Finally what you claim follows.

Comment: thank you so much! I am so dumb.

Comment: You are not dumb, it is just not going a step further, that is all. You are welcome! @ghjk